# Design pattern to keep behavior unique but make differ according to interfaces

Tags: java, design-patterns, interface

I'm looking for the name of the design pattern I just crafted and whether or not it's a good one.

So basically I was looking for a way to hold a main behavior among subclasses of an Actor class, divided in sub-behaviors that would differ based on which subinterfaces the subclass implements.

Here's a simplified example to make my point easier to understand...

An Actor Class :

```
public abstract class Actor implements FirstSubBehavior, SecondSubBehavior/*, MoreBehaviors...*/{
    
    public final void mainBehavior(){
        
        doFirstSubBehavior();
        doSecondSubBehavior();
        /* ... */
        //doNthSubBehavior();
        System.out.println();
        
    }
    
}
```

A FirstSubBehavior Interface :

```
public interface FirstSubBehavior{
    
    public void doFirstSubBehavior();
    
    public interface FirstWay extends FirstSubBehavior{
        
        public default void doFirstSubBehavior(){
            
            System.out.println("I'm doing the 1st sub-behavior using the 1st way.");
            
        }
        
    }
    
    public interface SecondWay extends FirstSubBehavior{
        
        public default void doFirstSubBehavior(){
            
            System.out.println("I'm doing the 1st sub-behavior using the 2nd way.");
            
        }
        
    }
    
    /* ... */
    
    public interface NthWay extends FirstSubBehavior{
        
        public default void doFirstSubBehavior(){
            
            System.out.println("I'm doing the 1st sub-behavior using the Nth way.");
            
        }
        
    }
    
}
```

A SecondSubBehavior Interface :

```
public interface SecondSubBehavior{
    
    public void doSecondSubBehavior();
    
    public interface FirstWay extends SecondSubBehavior{
        
        public default void doSecondSubBehavior(){
            
            System.out.println("I'm doing the 2nd sub-behavior using the 1st way.");
            
        }
        
    }
    
    public interface SecondWay extends SecondSubBehavior{
        
        public default void doSecondSubBehavior(){
            
            System.out.println("I'm doing the 2nd sub-behavior using the 2nd way.");
            
        }
        
    }
    
    /* ... */
    
    public interface NthWay extends SecondSubBehavior{
        
        public default void doSecondSubBehavior(){
            
            System.out.println("I'm doing the 2nd sub-behavior using the Nth way.");
            
        }
        
    }
    
}
```

And a Main Class to test it all :

```
public class Main{
    
    public static void main(String[] args){
        
        class Actor1 extends Actor implements FirstSubBehavior.FirstWay, SecondSubBehavior.FirstWay {}
        
        new Actor1().mainBehavior();
        
        class Actor2 extends Actor implements FirstSubBehavior.FirstWay, SecondSubBehavior.NthWay {}
        
        new Actor2().mainBehavior();
        
    }
    
}
```

This produces the following output :

```
I'm doing the 1st sub-behavior using the 1st way.
I'm doing the 2nd sub-behavior using the 1st way.

I'm doing the 1st sub-behavior using the 1st way.
I'm doing the 2nd sub-behavior using the Nth way.
```

So the main is important, in there you can see how I want to use my Actor class : I want to code ONCE the main behavior of all my subclasses, but then being able to make it differ based on which default sub-behavior it implements.

Hope I was clear, I can reformulate if it's not.

Comment: It seems like "multiple inheritance" is the best description, but a real Strategy setup where each of the behaviors is a field on a single fixed class is usually more effective in practice.

Comment: Design Patterns are solutions to problems. What problem does your "design pattern" solve?

Comment: So I google all of it and it looks like I was just looking for the Strategy Pattern in my case, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read carefully about [Liskov substitute](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle). So your pattern undermines determined behavior.

Problems that occur:

- What if state transition between two steps needs to be atomic/ transactional? (All or none)
- What if one throws a RuntimeException while following steps already acquired resources?
- What if a condition down the chain requires changes up the chain?

Such chaining patterns already exist but as valid Liskov substitutes:

- Servlets have a filter chain, clear restrictions by the interface. State change is possible like session memory or request wrapping.
- Validators only collect errors or fail fast, no state change on the validated objects. (Which is more a general contract since nothing keeps a validator instance from also invoking set-methods unless true immutables are validated.)
- State transition through commands. Each command binds a change and can be done, undone or re-done. The sequence of commands forms a chain to change one or more entities. Order does never change as well as the change/ the command itself is immutable.
- A strategy is a better pattern to have a contract on one side and a variety of implementations. For example construction of XML-readers or writers depends on the classpath yielding general interfaces.

I always prefer the strategy approach but also like one comment suggested: for a particular purpose. You need to read lines of String or a set of dedicated records from various resources: have a strategy per resource type. The contract is expressed as interface like:

```
public interface LineReader {
  List<String> readAll();
}
```

This can be realized by a FileLineReader, a StreamLineReader and/ or a UserInputReader. This is then chained like:

```
// already unmodifiable, factory classes/ methods
final List<Command> commandChain=Commands.forUsecase(UseCase.READ_TRANSFORM_PERSIST);

final Processor p=new Processor();

// only proceeds upon valid records
p.setPrecondition(Validators.fixedLengthRecordStyle());
// set of commands doing something with the context and data
p.setCommandChain(commandChain);
// Where to take data from
p.setSource(new FileLineReader(new File("/tmp/input.csv", LineFilters.skipEmptyLinesAndComments())));

// now there's a result
final ProcessingResult pr = p.process();

if (!pr.isValid()) {
  // print validation errors and exit
}

if (!pr.isSuccessful()) {
  // print processing errors and exit
}

// print success and exit.
System.printf("Read %d records, stored %d records, %d were duplicates", 
  pr.getNumberOfRecords(), pr.getNumberOfSaved(), 
  pr.getNumberOfSkipped());
```

Comment: Thank you for this very complete answer!